# Cannot stop NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nstimer

I know have many question like that on stackoverflow but with me. I still cannot stop my NSTimer. Below is my code:

```
func setupTimerForRecord(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timeStick:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    })
}
```

and function stop:

```
func resetTimmerLabel(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
        self.timeMin = 0
        self.timeSec = 0
        var timeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", arguments: [self.timeMin, self.timeSec])
        self.lblTimer.text = timeString
    })
}
```

function selector:

```
func timeStick(timer: NSTimer){
    print("timeStick")
    self.timeSec++
    if self.timeSec == 60{
        self.timeSec = 0
        self.timeMin++
    }
    var timeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", arguments: [self.timeMin, self.timeSec])
    lblTimer.text = timeString
}
```

call **setupTimerForRecord** at button clicked. and **resetTimmerLabel** at **viewWillDisappear** but the function **timeStick** still run. Please help me

**Edit** SORRY for my stupid mistake. The problem is I create another new one timer var timer. It must self.timer into the function **setupTimerForRecord**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you're creating a duplicate local variable called timer in setupTimerForRecord() . Set it to self.timer instead.

```
func setupTimerForRecord(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timeStick:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    })
}
```

Comment: You're right. I will accept your answer ASAP.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = NSTimer()

func setupTimerForRecord(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
       self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timeStick:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    })
}
```

Create timer variable globally. I mean outside the all functions. Best practice is create all the variable before viewDidLoad() normally who are require in other fucntions.

Comment: Not me down vote but the method **scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval** will create and return a timer. It doesn't need add **var timer = NSTimer()**